# Lots of question related to weight lose, fatty tissue etc in daily. Is it added intentionally?

Tags: support

I think some people are intentionally add question related weight lose, fatty tissue etc. Which is like a spam !!!!

Comment: Those are Spams!. Just flag such posts as SPAM. Moderators take necessary action on those posts and users.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, spam; the bane of the internet. Please flag it as spam if possible - this adds signal to various algorithms we use to try to minimize it (seriously, you should see the stuff that *doesn't* get through to appear on the site; it is... scary). If the problem has gotten *particularly* worse, please provide some example links I can look at to try to tune things.

---

k; with the info from the linked posts and some referenced posts, I have more context;

- most of these are from different IPs and different user accounts
- most of them are linking to different sites (although one was recurring)

I've blacklisted the recurring site and some recurring terms that should be pretty rare for drupal, however this is a very complicated problem to solve in the general case; hopefully we can reduce the impact a bit (or a lot), though.

Comment: Is one question take to attention after getting 10 flag?

Comment: @Smalution I can't quite understand what you are asking there; posts with more than a handful of spam flags (I forget the exact number but less than 10 IIRC) are deleted automatically; posts with a *single* spam flag are highly visible to site moderators to review.

Comment: I'm afraid than in last two to six weeks problem indeed got worse. See my flagging history if you can. Or [1](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127331) [2](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127330) [3](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127113) [4](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127071) [5](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127069) [6](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127062) and so on. As you can see, it is one type of spam, and numbers are in almost continuous series. Like one algorithm that found a way to pierce your protection.

Comment: Actually, I flagged 2 or 3 more since my previous comment. Should I link them, too?

Comment: @Mołot no, that's fine; I can access your flagging history; see update

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. Too bad I can't translate why they "feel alike" into something easily implemented as algorithm.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Review the link once http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127433/breguet-replica-watches-no-one-to-take-back-80  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127437/the-1solution-to-this-problem-lies-in-doppler-shift

Comment: Today i am seeing lots of spam post(more than 10).

Comment: I'm afraid @Smalution is right. 6 spam posts in last 2 hours for me to flag. And older ones was on the edge of flag deletion already, so I dare to guess I missed at least about a half, flagged sooner by other users. Not to mention answers, they may stay unnoticed longer. It is getting worse.

Comment: Still we are getting lots of spam post. Current i have flagged 5 spam posts.

Answer (score 1):

In order for us to block spam, folks have got to see it and identify it. We're working on things that reduce the amount that humans have to see even more, but even with that in place, established sites are going to see some spam posts every day - that's just (unfortunately) what the Internet has grown into.

This particular wave is coming from what I suspect to be an army of *hundreds of thousands* of infected computers, web servers and possibly phones. I *hate* the fact that spam punishes you for your own success - the better you rank in search results, the more these sleazeballs want to plant their links.

Stuff that we're doing in the quality initiative will effectively prevent any of this from ever being shown on the front page, or tag pages - it'll immediately hit a triage queue where folks dispose of it quickly. But, a few people are still going to need to see it.

Just flag it as spam - and move on, that's the best thing you can do. Every time you do that, you help to train our systems, and they do keep a *massive* amount of it out. This from just today:

[image: smells like meat, but it's not!]

You'll notice two things - one that we're actually seeing *less* of it over the last few days and 2 - that users don't need to work any harder than they normally do to keep a *huge* amount of it out of the system. A few hundred flags every day from around the network (roughly 2 posts spam-flag deleted per day per site) are all that's really needed 
to keep things pretty clean.

We're going to keep working as hard as we can to reduce the amount of work folks have to put into this even more, but there's never going to be a time where you don't see a bit of it - at least as long as scum bags are allowed to use the Internet.