# Please introduce anti-spam restrictions

Tags: feature-request, spam, links

Due to large amount of SPAM these days (see [Lots of question related to weight lose, fatty tissue etc in daily. Is it added intentionally?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3058/16495)) I propose to introduce following restrictions for unregistered or 1rep users:

- No links. And nothing reassembling a link, like www.example.com without `http://` and link tags
- No images. Yes, there was SPAM with images in the queue.

I know it looks drastic, but when I logged in today, I've seen 5 newest posts on my screen (first impression without scrolling), 4 of which was SPAM posts. I'm getting tired, and judging by the question linked, other users are affected, too.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Today, I've flagged 11 SPAMS in just 50 mins. Infact I opened DA meta to post about this. Glad you've already posted :)

Comment: Disallowing images might make sense here, but banning links would likely get very frustrating for new users. I think the price would be too high.

Comment: @MadScientist I believe links to imgur, php.net and *.drupal.org could stay allowed. Other links? why? Link-only answers are already forbidden. We expect content posted here to be link-independent, valid and complete even if linked resource disappears. Only "cost" I see would be disappearance of "here is my site, debug it plz" questions and "this link solves it" answers, but that would actually be a benefit.

Comment: I believe this has been discussed several times on MSE if someone wants to find some references.  I fully support this.

Comment: @MPD I think it was, too. But what we are seeing here, now, is substantially worse than anything what happened there. And I hardly ever see so much SPAM visiting RPG, UX or Arcade. Maybe they delete it faster? But I'm under impression that Drupal Answers became a designated target.

Comment: @Mołot DA has always been a spam favorite.  The Webapps, Ubuntu, and Apple sites, too.  There has been a slight uptick, but nothing too crazy.  I think you are seeing more of it because of when it usually gets posted.  By the time I wake up, I never see the spam flags.

Comment: @MPD point is: I'm getting up at the same time I always did, and I see a lot more spam than half a year ago or so. Or even 3 months ago.

Comment: I agree with molot introduce anti-spam restrictions, also  restrict the users first day Q&A posting limit something like they can post upto 3 Q&A.

Comment: @Bala I see no point, at least no anti-spam point, in posts per day per user restrictions. Spambots posts only one post per user created.